# Creating Dictionary Application for mobile

Tags: android, android-widget

I wanted to create Urdu-Hindi-English dictionary application for mobile in Android.

The dictionary content would be some thing like this:
H اببهاگ अबभाग ababhāg [S. अव+भाग], s.m. Adverse fortune; misfortune, ill-luck.

I have 3 questions related to this:

1) Whats the procedure to create the mobile application in Android; Please provide a link; most of the links in net is not very clear. If have some resource or link plz share.

2)
The above entry contains 3 languages ( Hindi; Urdu; English ) would it be possible to such an entry's in different languages does android allows us to do it if so how? please provide the links,suggestion or sample examples.

3) Will there be any limitations on the database for the mobile application form the software prospective(not from mobile). Since dictionary entries will be around 2 million.

I will be very gratitude with if someone provides the solution to my problem. 
Also if I am able to create this one then I will share it.

Awaiting for the Ans....

Answer (score 0):

1) Try reading through the android developer site at http://developer.android.com
There is some good introductory material there that will teach you how to write applications for Android (for example, try here: http://developer.android.com/training/index.html)

2) Yes, that is not a problem. You will have to use custom fonts, since the built-in fonts don't have support for Urdo and Hindi characters. There are several free Urdu and Hindi fonts available (search for Urdu TTF, for example), and you can load these from within your application.

3) Yes, certainly there are limitations. I'm not sure if a database of that size can be created on mobile devices. You may have to split the dictionary in sections, with a different database for each section.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Edovino..!! I will give it a try; And regarding the splitting up the dictionary into sections i will try to explore more on this. Thanks Again..

Answer (score 0):

All dictionary app usages a micro database sqlite.
Some apps are based on this concept like:

[English to Hindi Dictionary](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hindi.dictionary)

[English to Arabic Dictionary](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smartappspro.englisharabicdictionary)